# Автосдвиг div

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!

Есть страничка с верхним блоком и нижним. Верхний блок по дефолту - высотой 200px, но когда информации заполняется больше, то текст налазит поверх нижнего блока. Как сделать, чтоб нижний блок просто сдвигался в низ, когда верхний расширяется?

Answer (score 2):

Если блоки расположены друг за другом в [потоке](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/ponyatie-potoka), то `min-height: 200px` для верхнего блока поможет вам.

Comment: Сейчас попробую..

Comment: Да спасибо работает=)

Answer (score 1):

Может вам стоит использовать min-height: 200px для верхнего блока?